# Publish Content in Drupal by One Editor Only

Tags: 7

Im a new Admin for an Educational E learning Portal Developed by drupal, the current status of publishing a Content is to be verified or reviewed by two Moderators or Editors. My Question is : How to make (1) Editor publish a content after Reviewing instead of 2?

The Current flow, A "teacher" publish an Educational Content as ( needs review: , then an Editor Reviews that content and then he chooses ONE OF THE FOLLOWING: 1) initial approve 2) send back to Edit " to the teacher" 3) Publish - BUT in order to publish another Editor must review and Publish it to be available as a published content.

the used workflow is the default workbench Flow, But nothing there mentions that 2 Editors must Review,

where can i Find such a code to edit? in which module Block ?

Thank you!

Comment: https://www.drupal.org/documentation/modules/workbench_moderation probably.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as i know, Workbench moderation module works based on user roles. The permission to change the state from needs review to published can be given to one or more roles. It is not possible to give permission to specific person.

In your case:

- Create a new state 'Ready to Publish'
- Add two state transitions, Needs Review -> Ready to Publish and Ready to Publish -> Published
- Make sure you remove the state transition Needs Review -> Published (Or you can revoke the permission for this state transition to editor role)
- Create a role called 'Publisher'
- Assign this role to second editor
- Give state transition permission Needs Review -> Ready to publish to editor role
- Give state transition permission Ready to publish -> Published to editor role.

With the above steps, teacher posts the content which will be in needs review state. Editor can review the content and can change the state to 'Ready to Publish'. Now, the second editor who has the role 'Publisher' can review the content and can publish.